# Windows Outlook defaults HTML font to Times New Roman

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter, outlook-2016

My html/css codes render correctly in Mac Outlook but Windows Outlook overrides fonts to Times New Roman. Below is the code to the email. Can someone let me know what am I missing?

```
     <style style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;">
            html, body {
                margin: 0 auto;
                   padding: 0;
                   height: 100%;
                   width: 100%;
            }
            * {
                -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
               }
            table, td {
                   mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
                   mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
               }
               img {
                   -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
               }
               a {
                  text-decoration: none;
            }
        </style>
<!--[if !mso]>
        <style type=”text/css”>
            body, table, td {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
        </style>
<![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#fff" style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;margin-top: 0;margin-right: auto;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: auto;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;height: 100%;width: 100%;" align="center">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed;display: block;width: 640px;margin-top: 0;margin-right:auto;margin-bottom: 0;margin-left: auto;padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" align="center">
```

Answer (score 0):

you've got an error in the conditional code where you're trying to target Outlook.

Rather than <!--[if !mso]>, **it should be <!--[if mso]>**.

With <!--[if !mso]>, you're saying 'if **NOT** mso'.